# Cant access (Javascript populated) dropdown selected value from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I cannot access the HTML drop down elements selected value from code behind(C#). The drop down is populated in clients side using java script.

```
                           <select id="cmbDOBMonth" class="dropDownListDOB" runat="server" onchange="calGetDate();">
                           <option value="0">Month:</option>
                           <option value="1">Jan</option>
                           </select>
```

i can access the cmbDOBMonth value but cannot access cmbDOBDate.

```
                           <select id="cmbDOBDate" runat="server" class="dropDownListDOB">
                           <option value="0">Date:</option>
                       </select>
```

Comment: @Abhidev cmbDOBDate.Value is always 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Page.Request.Form["cmbDOBDate"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This code to get value of date dropdownlist:
Use the javascript as below:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function calGetDate() {
            var e = document.getElementById("cmbDOBDate");
            alert(e);
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(strUser);          
        };
    </script>
```

Now write your html dropdownlist as follow:

```
<select id="cmbDOBDate" class="dropDownListDOB" onchange="calGetDate();">
        <option value="0">Date:</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
```

Now you can access your date dropdownlist also.

Comment: Yes, ur correct. My problem is not getting the selected value in client side. I want to retrieve the selected value in server side. This is my javascript to populate the cmbDOBDate combobox - 
function popDate(date)
{

var cmbdt=document.getElementById("cmbDOBDate");
cmbdt.options.length = 0;

cmbdt.options[0]=new Option("Date:",0);
        for (var i = 1 ; i <= date; i++) { 
            cmbdt.options[i]=new Option(i,i.toString());
        }
}; i want to get the selected value of this combox in server side.

Answer (score 0):

By this following Example you can get value or text of html combobox on label serverside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getHTMLSelectOptionText() {
            var SelectOption = document.getElementById("drpdwn");
            var SelectedIndex = SelectOption.selectedIndex;
            var SelectedValue = SelectOption.value;
            var SelectedText = SelectOption.options[SelectOption.selectedIndex].text;

            var LabelDropdownList = document.getElementById('<%=lblSelectOptionText.ClientID %>');
            var sValue = 'Index: ' + SelectedIndex + ' Selected Value: ' + SelectedValue + ' Selected Text: ' + SelectedText;

            LabelDropdownList.innerHTML = sValue;
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2">HTML Select Option</asp:Label><br />
        <select name="HTMLSelect" onchange="getHTMLSelectOptionText();" id="drpdwn">
            <option value="Asp">Free Asp.net articles/Code examples</option>
            <option value="Sqlserver">Free Sql server articles/Code examples</option>
            <option value="Javascript">Free Javascript articles/Code examples</option>
            <option value="XML">Free XML articles/Code examples</option>
            <option value="Gridview">Free Asp.net Gridview articles/Code examples</option>
        </select>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSelectOptionText"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```